# Delete specified column VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Hi just trying to run a code on every sheet in a workbook. For some reason it wont delete the column as specified. I've also tried using `Columns(“A”).Delete` and that did not work either

```
Sub Format()

'Firstly convert all text cells into number cells for every sheet in workbook

For Each WS In Sheets
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each r In WS.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        If IsNumeric(r) Then r.Value = (r.Value) * 1
        ''Or test the values in the next column on the right
        'If IsNumeric(r) Then r.Offset(0,1).Value = (r.Value)*1
    Next r

    Rows("1:15").Delete
    Columns(“1”).Delete


Next WS

End Sub
```

Comment: `Columns("A")` would work, as long as you also specified the worksheet: `ws.Columns("A").Delete`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't qualifying those references with the sheet... it should look like this:

```
WS.Rows("1:15").Delete
WS.Columns(1).Delete
```

If you don't do that, then it just assumes `ActiveSheet` each time it loops.

Notice also that you do not put the `1` for columns in quotes. The `1` is an index value, not a string value.

Also, the type of quotes you are using is wrong. Look closely:

```
WS.Columns(“A”).Delete  ' <--- these curly quotes will not work (they are not the same thing)

WS.Columns("A").Delete  ' <--- these straight quotes work
```

[straight and curly quotes](https://typographyforlawyers.com/straight-and-curly-quotes.html)